# How to hide an element after $compile?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is a directive:

```
.directive('location', function () {
        return {
            restrict : 'A',
            scope    : {},
            replace  : true,
            templateUrl: 'common/components/location/location.html',
            link     : function (scope, element, attr) {……}
        }
});
```

So it is used in another directive:

```
var scope     =  $rootScope.$new(true);                
var directive = $compile('<div location></div>')(scope);

$document.find('body').append(directive);

directive.hide(); - not working
```

How to hide directive generated html after inserting it to body? Directive has "replace" set to true

http://plnkr.co/edit/e7fNua?p=preview

Comment: Do you have jquery included?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: No errors, just the element remains visible.

Comment: Please create a plunkr

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/e7fNua?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line you've marked as wrong is **actually working** meaning that after `directive.hide()` if you print the element on console you'll see:

```
console.log(directive[0]);
-> <div location="" class="ng-scope" style="display: none;"></div>
```

This one is a bit tricky but easy if you carefully follow what you told angular to perform. Let's go through it step by step

1. `$compile('<div location></div>')(scope);` - here you're telling angular to `compile` given template and `link` it with given `scope`. Since you have specified `templateUrl` that must be fetched **angular has not yet completed** processing this element.
2. `$document.find('body').append(directive); directive.hide();` - append the element to `body` and immediately `hide` it. If you print the `directive[0]` to console you'll see: `<div location="" class="ng-scope" style="display: none;"></div>`

   **Note that there is still no `<section><p>Text</p></section>` inside DOM**
3. Angular completes fetching `location.html` template.
4. Since you have `replace: true` inside directive declaration the `directive[0]` is **removed** from DOM and replaced by compiled `<section><p>Text</p></section>`.

As a result you still see *Text* on page.

You can change this behaviour in various ways:

- change directive declaration to `replace: false`
- use inline `template: '<section><p>Text</p></section>'`
- wrap template that you pass to `$compile` in another element: `$compile('<div class="wrapped"><div location></div></div>')`